# How should questions about licensing be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a few questions on Movies & TV about whether creators had permission to use copyrighted characters/music.

How should these questions be tagged?

**Should a new [licensing](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing) tag be created? Or should these be tagged as [copyright](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright)?**

- [Is the face on the front of the truck a Marvel approved likeness of the Green Goblin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78505/is-the-face-on-the-front-of-the-truck-a-marvel-approved-likeness-of-the-green-go)
- [Did Fox need permission for the 'Spider-Pig' parody in The Simpsons Movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71817/did-fox-need-permission-for-the-spider-pig-parody-in-the-simpsons-movie)
- [How did The LEGO Batman movie get away with using characters from many different franchises?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72427/how-did-the-lego-batman-movie-get-away-with-using-characters-from-many-different)
- [How did Preacher get away with an exploding Tom Cruise?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64950/how-did-preacher-get-away-with-an-exploding-tom-cruise)
- [How did a clip from Eurotrip end up in Katy Perry's Last Friday Night?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62793/how-did-a-clip-from-eurotrip-end-up-in-katy-perrys-last-friday-night)

Comment: Tag wiki excerpt for [tag:copyright]: "A legal concept that grants the creator of an original work exclusive rights to its use and distribution."

Comment: I'm kinda meh on this.  Is there anyone that actually searches by this tag?

Comment: @DForck42 I've searched it a few times. I find questions about copyright and licensing fairly interesting.

Comment: then I say let's just keep using the copyright tag.  licenses are typically in regards to copyrighted material anyway